# Creating popup boxes using html css and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup, box

basically i'm trying to create multiple popup boxes that appear when different links are clicked. For some reason, a popup box only appears when the first link is clicked. When the rest of the links are clicked, nothing happens. Any help is appreciated, thanks. Also, I've only included 2 of the links in this example.

javascript code:

```
function xpopup() {
        document.getElementById("x").onclick= function(){
            var overlay = document.getElementById("overLay");
            var popup = document.getElementById("xPopup");
            overlay.style.display = "block";
            popup.style.display = "block";
        }
    }

    function ypopup() {
        document.getElementById("y").onclick= function(){
            var overlay = document.getElementById("overLay");
            var popup = document.getElementById("yPopup");
            overlay.style.display = "block";
            popup1.style.display = "block";
        }
    }
    </script>
```

HTML code:

```
 <body onLoad="xpopup()"; "ypopup()";>
 <div id="overLay"></div>

<div class="popupBox" id="xPopup"></div>
<div class="popupBox" id="yPopup"></div>

<a href="#" class="listAttractions" id="x">Link 1</a><br>
<a href="#" class="listAttractions" id="y">Link 2</a><br>
```

CSS code:

```
.popupBox{
display:none;
position: fixed;
width: 30%;
height: 40%;
margin-left: 16.5%; 
margin-top: 4.5%;
background-color: white;
border: 2px solid black;
border-radius: 10px;
z-index: 10;
}

#overLay{
display:none;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: #707070;
opacity: 0.7; 
z-index: 9;
left: 0;
top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `<body onLoad="xpopup()"; "ypopup()";>` with `<body onLoad="xpopup(); ypopup();">` and in your JavaScript code you have a typo.

```
function ypopup() {
    document.getElementById("y").onclick= function(){
        var overlay = document.getElementById("overLay");
        var popup = document.getElementById("yPopup");
        overlay.style.display = "block";
        popup1.style.display = "block";    // Here the popup1 is undefined change it to popup.style.....
    }
}
```

### Edit :-->

I've changed your code to hide the popup, if you click on the greyed out section.

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0dpt60q4/)

#### HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="overLay"></div>
    <div class="popupBox" id="xPopup"></div>
    <div class="popupBox" id="yPopup"></div>
<a href="#" class="listAttractions" id="x">Link 1</a>
    <br />
<a href="#" class="listAttractions" id="y">Link 2</a>
    <br />
</body>
```

#### JavaScript:

```
var overlay = document.getElementById("overLay");
var xpopup = document.getElementById("xPopup");
var ypopup = document.getElementById("yPopup");

document.getElementById("x").onclick = function () {
    overlay.style.display = "block";
    xpopup.style.display = "block";
};
document.getElementById("y").onclick = function () {
    overlay.style.display = "block";
    ypopup.style.display = "block";
};
overlay.onclick = function () {
    overlay.style.display = "none";
    xpopup.style.display = "none";
    ypopup.style.display = "none";
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much you absolute don!

Comment: @ZaqMughal - Check out my edited answer. This is how I would do it.

Comment: Yeah I realized after that changing them into global variables would be better. Where you have used the 'overlay.onclick = function () {........'     does that mean that when the user clicks anywhere outside the popup box, the pop up box closes?

Comment: @ZaqMughal - Yes exactly.

Comment: Got it, what I've done is added a HTML close symbol to the top right of my popup as the popup contains a form and I don't want the user getting half way through the form and accidentally closing the popup by clicking outside of the box.

Comment: @ZaqMughal - If my answer helped you out can you please make my answer as accepted by clicking on the check mark below the up and down arrows beside the answer and give me an upvote?

Comment: All done but do not have 15 'reputation' so cannot give upvote.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing two issues --

The first is already answered by chipChocolate.py:

> Replace `<body onLoad="xpopup()"; "ypopup()";>` with `<body onLoad="xpopup(); ypopup();">`.

The second (and maybe this is just a typo?) is that you have:

```
function ypopup() {
  document.getElementById("y").onclick= function()
    var overlay = document.getElementById("overLay");
    var popup = document.getElementById("yPopup");
    overlay.style.display = "block";
    popup1.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

You're referencing `popup1` but you've named your variable `popup`. If you open up the javascript console you'll probably see that's throwing an error. Rename the variable `popup1` and this should work.

Comment: Yeah annoying little typo, thanks for spotting mate.